# Can Saxon work on a page with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, xquery, saxon

Due to some issues with the php version of Saxon, I currently have a convoluted setup where I do a php call to execute a java command, convert the results into html, display that html on my page, and then delete the resulting html after display.  I can provide a link to the page if it helps, but the actual .xq file is pretty simplistic:

```
xquery version "1.0" encoding "UTF-8";

declare namespace tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0";

declare variable $zone external;
declare variable $line external;
declare variable $collection external;

declare function local:if-empty
  ( $arg as item()? ,
    $value as item()* )  as item()* {

  if (string($arg) != '')
  then data($arg)
  else $value
 };

declare function local:remove-elements($input as element(), $remove-names as xs:string*) as element() {
   element {node-name($input) }
      {$input/@*,
       for $child in $input/node()[not(name(.)=$remove-names)]
          return
             if ($child instance of element())
                then local:remove-elements($child, $remove-names)
                else $child
      }
};

declare function local:remove-empty-elements($nodes as node()*)  as node()* {
   for $node in $nodes
   return
     if (empty($node)) then () else
     if ($node instance of element())
     then if (normalize-space($node) = '')
          then ()
          else element { node-name($node)}
                { $node/@*,
                  local:remove-empty-elements($node/node())}
     else if ($node instance of document-node())
     then local:remove-empty-elements($node/node())
     else $node
 } ;

<list>
{
let $q:=collection($collection)
let $remove-list := ('note')

(:let $q:=local:remove-empty-elements($q):)

for $y in $q 
let $s := $y//tei:surface   
let $t := $y//tei:titleStmt/@xml:id
let $m := $y//tei:msDesc/@xml:id
let $z := $s/tei:zone[@n=$zone]
let $l := $z/tei:line[@n=$line]
let $w := concat($y//tei:msDesc/tei:msIdentifier/tei:settlement/text(),', ',$y//tei:msDesc/tei:msIdentifier/tei:institution/text(),' ',$y//tei:msDesc/tei:msIdentifier/tei:idno/text())
let $g := concat($t, "/" , $m, "/", substring-before($l/../../tei:graphic/@url,"."),".html")
let $o:=local:remove-elements($l/tei:orig,$remove-list)
where ($z//tei:line/@n = "l.1")


return 

<item>{$w}: <ref target="{$g}">{$o}</ref></item>}
</list>
```

and the command to run it is `java -Xms128m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseCompressedOops -cp saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -t -q:test.xq -o:1505740041.41932650059544.xml line=l.4 zone=EETS.QD.8 collection=file:<filefolder>`

My problem is that the xml files I'm working with are currently unpublished transcriptions, and I'd like to keep them behind a password protected folder until I think they're ready for prime time.  If I have any sort of .htaccess file in the filefolder location, I get the following error message:

```
Building tree for file:<filefolder>/.htaccess using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
Error on line 1 column 1 of .htaccess:
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Query failed with dynamic error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:<filefolder>/.htaccess; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

It's pretty obvious to me that what's happening is that it's getting to the .htaccess file, which is not XML, and then doesn't know what to do with it.  My question is if there's a way in my xquery file to tell Saxon not to include .htaccess in the collection.  I'm sure there is, but everything I've found is about finding file names, not about suppressing them in the collection you're building.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ever need something more elaborate than selection using a glob pattern, then you can use the `uri-collection()` function to return the URIs of the files in the directory, and then use `doc()` to process the ones that you are actually interested in. This would give you a solution if, for example, you wanted everything that doesn't start with ".", regardless of its extension.

Another thing you can do with `uri-collection()` is to process each returned URI within a try/catch block so you have full control over the error handling.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm just stupid.  The solution is to add a concat statement to append the select info to the $collection variable, like so:

```
let $collection:=concat($collection, '?select=*.xml')
let $q:=collection($collection)
let $remove-list := ('note')
```